# z-index in half of shape

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to make shape as below:

[image]

I tried so far but how can I hybrid those together:

```css
.clal-loader{
  display:flex;
}
.clal-loader div{
  border: 10px solid #38477e;
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.clal-loader div:nth-child(1){
   border-color:#0cabec;
}

.clal-loader div:nth-child(2){
 transform: rotate(-180deg);
     position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="clal-loader">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want the gradient coloration or only one color?

Comment: You cannot do that with plain CSS and only two elements. Either you need to use an svg image or split one of the elements into two. There is only one `z-index` possible per element.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I do not mean the color I mean to the skyblue insert down the blue in bottom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would consider radial-gradient and only one element like below. Basically they are 4 similar gradient each one creating a quarter circle and you adjust the order to have the final shape:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, transparent 40%,blue  40%, blue  60%,transparent 61%) top,  
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom right,transparent 40%,green 40%, green 60%,transparent 61%) top,
    radial-gradient(circle at top right,   transparent 40%,green 40%, green 60%,transparent 61%) bottom,
    radial-gradient(circle at top left,    transparent 40%,blue  40%, blue  60%,transparent 61%) bottom;
    
  background-size:100% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

With two elements you can consider both pseudo element of each div to create the same think as the first code then all you have to do is to adjust `z-index`.

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}
.box > div {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
.box > div:before,
.box > div:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:70%;
  height:50%;
}

.box > div:first-child {
  color:red;
}

.box > div:last-child {
  color:blue;
}

.box > div:first-child::before {
  z-index:1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  border-top:15px solid;
  border-right:15px solid;
  border-top-right-radius:100%;
}
.box > div:first-child::after {
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  border-bottom:15px solid;
  border-right:15px solid;
  border-bottom-right-radius:100%;
}
.box > div:last-child::before {
  top:0;
  right:0;
  border-top:15px solid;
  border-left:15px solid;
  border-top-left-radius:100%;
}
.box > div:last-child::after {
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  border-bottom:15px solid;
  border-left:15px solid;
  border-bottom-left-radius:100%;
}

*,*::before,*::after {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. Awesome as allways...but I want to do it with 2 elements because i want make some animation to those...